# Upon compiling my Visual C++ file in visual studio, a 3D object file is created instead of an object file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I tried to compile a simple Hello world file in visual studio 2019 to look at the object file. However in the directory, the object file has been marked as 3D object (.obj) file.
How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't really need to fix anything. It's not going to harm you that `.obj` is associated with 3D imaging software. The compiler will not care it does not use this association (file extension to application) in the build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to fix anything. It's not going to harm you that `.obj` is associated with 3D imaging software. The compiler will not care. It does not use this association (file extension to application) in any part of the build process.

Comment: But what if I want to see the object file?

Comment: I am confused at what you expect to see. An object file is your compiled code for a single source file. You could use a disassembler to see the assembly language dump. It's not a runable program.

Comment: @KumaravelRajan • you can use [DUMPBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2019) to see the object file.

Comment: Yes the command line utility DUMPBIN can be used to show the symbols contained in the object file, the disassembly ...

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the tip everyone!